# How to avoid duplicate mount that was happened by mistake in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, fstab

I want to share all our lesson learning about mistake that happened on our production very critical server (RHE 7.6 version).

The story is about some mistake in our code that performed by mistake. Duplicate mount on the same mounted folder according to `fstab`.

In short, we did mistake and add duplicate lines in `fstab`, therefore we actually mounted on existing mount.

Here is example from `mount` command:

```
/dev/sda /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdc ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdd ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdd /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdb ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sde /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sde ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/987 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=51145428k,mode=700,uid=987,gid=976 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1005 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=51145428k,mode=700,uid=1005,gid=1005 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/0 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=51145428k,mode=700 0 0
/dev/sda /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdb ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdc ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdd /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdd ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

as we can see above we get duplicate 3 mounted on :

```
/DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdb
/DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdc
/DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdd
```

So in order to avoid such of below mistakes, we are wondering if we can do something in order to avoid such of this mistakes even if they happen.

For example, maybe some conf in `fstab` that avoid duplicate mount or anything else.

Comment: Did this actually cause problems? Linux supports multiple mounts per filesystem; it's not a corruption risk.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The output of the `mount` command is not reliable on modern versions of Linux. Use `findmnt` or `cat /proc/self/mountinfo` instead.

Comment: the output of mount and /proc/self/mountinfo are the same with the same problem as I explained

Comment: Will adding to the `mount` the parameter `--make-unbindable` help? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: sorry but not understand do you mean to add it to the line in fstab?

Comment: @KingDavid: Yes, that's what I mean. The option might be called `unbindable`. (I wasn't notified about your comment - add `@harrymc` for instant notification.)

Comment: @harrymc "An unbindable mount is a private mount which cannot be cloned through a bind operation." (`man mount`) - so that's not it. The solution is (I guess) to not do this in the first place, according to the `man` page there is no safeguard.

Comment: The ❝/dev/sda /DATA_FROM_LINKEDIN/sdb❞ appeared because of a software bug, right? First of all, fix you bugs. By the way, Ī̲ expect linux to refuse to mount a device which is already mounted anywhere.

Comment: @user1686 probably confuses `mount --bind` and similar tricks (which are not a “true” mount) with mounting a block device. Any specific block device cannot be mounted if it is already mounted.